# Ajax Validation of UNIQUE - how to show and set error in the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, validation

I am using native HTML5 validation for almost all rules, 
but for UNIQUE, obviously, I have to make server side validation.
I have JS to make AJAX request and ask controller if current input (onkeydown) is unique. 
I am getting right response from server.
How should I show error message with input in native HTML5 style and also set it as not valid to not allow user to submit form?
I was trying to find it but I cannot understand it, as if I call:

```
$('#alias').get(0).setCustomValidity('Alias is taken already.');
```

Nothing is happening.

Comment: normaly that's the way you do it. but the message will only be shown if you sent the form. so: prevent the submit, make the ajax call, set the validity and after that: submit the form a second time :)

Comment: any example? I am not sure if I understand you.
I want to update and show/hide this message live, so during the typing